# Where and how is operator new implemented?

Tags: c++, new-operator

This may be a silly question as I'm quite new to the implementations of operators in C++...

I've been using the `new` operator/expression/keyword for a while. But I've just noticed that there is a function called `operator new`. As far as I know, in most cases, the `new` operator calls the "default" `operator new` first to allocate raw memory for the object it is required to create, and then calls the constructor of the object to create the object on that memory. And we're allowed to override the default `operator new` both in global scope or in a class.

I wonder where the (default) `operator new` is defined. On one hand, I don't think it is defined in `std`, because if I do:

```cpp
std::operator new(42);
```

Visual studio says `namespace "std" has no member "operator new"`. Moreover, `operator new(42);` runs successfully when I'm neither including any standard header nor `using namespace std;`.

On the other hand, I found that if I do:

```cpp
include <iostream>
int main() { operator new(42); }
```

Visual Studio then tells me that the `operator new` I am using is something as follows:

```cpp
_NODISCARD _Ret_notnull_ _Post_writable_byte_size_(_Size) _VCRT_ALLOCATOR
void* __CRTDECL operator new(
    size_t _Size
    );
```

which is declared in `vcruntime_new.h` (which is in turn `include`d by `<new>`). Whereas if I comment out `include <iostream>`, Visual Studio tells me that I am using something as:

```cpp
void *operator new(unsigned long long)
```

which `is not located in a source code file.`

So I think `operator new` has something to do with the standard library. Could anyone please clarify on what actually happens to `operator new` in those situations?

Another thing that I am confusing about is that if the program somehow includes `vcruntime_new.h`, then I may guess that the compiler sees `void* __CRTDECL operator new` to be in global scope. Now, if we define our own `void* operator new(std::size_t);` in global scope, the compiler will choose to use the `operator new` defined by us instead of the one defined in `vcruntime_new.h`, and there is no ambiguity. May I ask how this is achieved?

Comment: C++ intellisense usually lies flat out. _Do not_ trust what it says. `std` library defines the default `new()` and `delete` operators, and their array versions.

Comment: _"...I wonder where the (default) operator new is defined. ..."_ in the global namespace [`operator new, operator new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

Comment: @TanveerBadar I don't think that is correct. `operator new` is in the global namespace

Comment: @john yup, I meant `std` as in the standard library, not the namespace. You are correct.

Comment: In addition when calling `::operator new` you __must__ `#include <new>`.  Standard library headers may include other standard library headers and other (internal) implementation headers.  You might not get the expected results if you don't include the required header(s) in your code.

Comment: @RichardCritten Not necessarily, at least according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). The standard versions of operator new and operator new[] are implicitly declared even if <new> is not included.

Comment: @john you are right.  I was rushing and just gave the general advice for _"why does this work / not work"_ if I don't include the headers.

Comment: I don't think there is any well defined mechanism by which the default global operator new is replaced. It's going to depend on the tool chain you are using.

Comment: @john see [__Global replacements__](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) _"... a user-provided non-member function with the same signature defined anywhere in the program, in any source file, replaces the default version. Its declaration does not need to be visible..."_ in the link

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, I agree. I meant something slightly different, the OPs question was why is there no ambiguity when replacing the default version. I assumed he meant by this how does the linker know which version to pick. I was just trying to say that this is not something that the C++ standard specifies, only that it must pick the replacement not the original

Comment: The default `operator new()` and its overloads are defined in the global namespace (not `std`). It is a bit special, because the standard explicitly allows a definition of it in any source file of your program to be used instead of the "default" one provided with your implementation (compiler/library).  How an implementation achieves that is unspecified by the standard but most (compile then link) toolchains sort that out when linking (e.g. an `operator new()` defined in one of your object files is used if found, otherwise the default one (e.g. in a library shipped with your compiler) is used)

Comment: @Peter may I ask if it is possible for us to implement controls at link-time? Or is such implementation exclusive for those who implement compilers and standard library?

Comment: @CPPL   If you read the documentation for your compiler and linker, I'd expect you could implement such "controls".  Since most developers use (rather than develop) toolchains (compiler, libraries, etc) I wouldn't expect too many would *need* to do that.   So it's not so much "exclusive" as it is "most folks don't need to".

Comment: There are open source linkers. If the existing controls are not enough, you can always add new ones. But before that you can modify the compiled binaries (e.g. ELF files) and libraries instead to modify the outcome. Read up about name mangling, strong and weak symbols.